# Nginx do not start with docker-compose run command

Tags: docker, nginx, server, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am dockerizing my existing application. But there's a strange issue. When i start my application with

```
docker-compose up
```

each service in the docker-compose runs successfully with no issues. But there are some services which i don't want to run sometimes (celery, celerybeat etc). For that i run

```
docker-compose run nginx
```

the above command should run nginx, web, db services as configured with docker-compose.yml but it only runs web and db not nginx.

Here's my yml file

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres:12
        env_file: .env
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
            - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
        ports:
            - "5431:5432"
        volumes:
            - dbdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    nginx:
        image: nginx:1.14
        ports:
            - "443:443"
            - "80:80"
        volumes:
            - ./config/nginx/:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./MyAPP/static:/var/www/MyAPP.me/static/
        depends_on:
            - web
    web:
        restart: always
        build: ./MyAPP
        command:  bash -c "
                    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput 
                    && python manage.py makemigrations
                    && python manage.py migrate
                    && gunicorn --certfile=/etc/certs/localhost.crt --keyfile=/etc/certs    /localhost.key MyAPP.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:443 --reload"
        expose:
            - "443"
        depends_on:
            - db
        env_file:
            - .env
        volumes:
            - ./MyAPP:/opt/MyAPP
            - ./config/nginx/certs/:/etc/certs
            - ./MyAPP/static:/var/www/MyAPP.me/static/

    broker:
        image: redis:alpine
        expose: 
            - "6379"
    
    celery:
        build: ./MyAPP
        command: celery -A MyAPP worker -l info
        env_file:
            - .env
        volumes:
            - ./MyAPP:/opt/MyAPP
        depends_on:
            - broker
            - db

    celery-beat:
        build: ./MyAPP
        command: celery -A MyAPP beat -l info
        env_file:
            - .env
        volumes:
            - ./MyAPP:/opt/MyAPP
        depends_on:
            - broker
            - db
    comment-classifier:
        image: codait/max-toxic-comment-classifier

volumes:
    dbdata:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;dr: `docker-compose up nginx`

There's a distinct difference between `docker-compose up` and `docker-compose run`. The first builds, (re)creates, starts, and attaches to containers for a service. The second runs a one-time command against a service. When you do `docker-compose run`, it starts db and web because nginx depends on them, then it runs a single command on nginx and exits. So you have to use `docker-compose up nginx` in order to get what you want.

Comment: Exactly what i wanted. Thank you.